# Definir matriz em python

Tags: python, matriz

Preciso criar uma matriz e preenchê-la com valores aleatórios (`randint(0,9)`), excepto nas linhas e colunas iguais. Por exemplo, desta forma:

```
   A| B| C| D| E
A  x| 2| 1| 4| 2 
B  1| x| 1| 1| 2
C  5| 1| x| 4| 3
D  8| 2| 1| x| 2
E  5| 4| 1| 4| x
```

Já fiz isto:

```
from random import randint


def matrix():

    n=5 
    m=10

    matrixC = []
    value = (randint(0,9))

    #adicionar esse valores à matriz gerada
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n):
            if i != j:
                matrizC.append[[random.random() for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
            else:
                matrizC.append("x")
```

[UPDATE]

Seguindo as indicações tenho isto:

```
from random import randint

def matriz():
    #pedir o n
    n=5
    matriz = []  #declaração da matriz

    n_col=1
    n_lin=1

    for n_lin in range(n):
        linha = [] # cria uma linha para a matriz
        for n_col in range(n):
            if n_lin==n_col:
                linha.append('x')               
            else:
                linha.append(randint(1,9))

    matriz.append(linha)

    n_col=1
    n_lin=1 

    for n_lin in range(n):
        for n_col in range(n):
            print(matriz[n_lin][n_col], end='\t')
```

No 3º for faço a impressão da matriz, mas ao compilar não obtenho nenhum resultado.

Comment: Não parece ter nada errado na pergunta - tem o código inicial da A.P., que tem algumas partes faltando, e uma resposta poderá orienta-la na direção certa.

Comment: Elaine, teria como [edit] seu post acrescentando uma breve explicação do que deu errado ou que não correspondeu à expectativa no código que tentou? O post começou bem, com detalhes relevantes, mas faltou uma descrição de onde exatamente está o problema, que é justamente a duvida de programação no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Acabou ficando uma "pergunta sem pergunta", mas acredito que uma simples edição complementando resolva.

Comment: esse é seu código todo? você sabe que em Python não há uma função com nome especial que é chamada automaticamente - e sim que o programa é executado do começo ao fim, e as funcções precisam ser chamadas. Pra ver algum resultado - mesmo que não seja o que você espera aí, você tem que chamar a função `matriz()  no corpo do módulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está misturando duas técnicas. Uma forma de fazer é usando os `for`s estruturados um em cada linha:

```
matriz = []
for n_lin in range(5):
    linha = [] # cria uma linha para a matriz
    for n_col in range(5):
        if n_lin == n_col:
            linha.append('x')
        else:
            linha.append(randint(0, 9))
    matriz.append(linha)
```

A outra forma é colocar tudo em uma linha só, a famosa "compreensão de lista":

```
matriz = [['x' if x == y else randint(0, 9) for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
```

Comment: Obrigada nosko, acho que assim já dá. Será que me puderias ajudar a imprimir esta matriz? Eu fiz como indico na edição, mas me dá output nenhm.

Comment: no seu código faltou chamar a função: uma linha  `matriz()` na coluna zero, no final do arquivo faria isso.